# An issue related to changing varchar to datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, etl, varchar

I have a question related to data type. Now I'm trying to import a flat file into my destination database.

1. I import the flat file into one table A inside my staging database. All the columns in table A are in  varchar(50) data type.
2. I wrote a SQL query to change the data type and clean the data in table A, and finally insert the clean data into table B inside the destination database.

Here is the question: there is one column in this file containing date data. It is in varchar(50) data type in table A. But it also contains empty rows. So in table A it looks fine: some rows are date and some rows are empty. However, after I run the SQL query. In table B, all the empty rows in table A are changed into 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. Please note I set this column in table B to be datetime data type.
Now I want the rows with date in this column to show date and the empty rows to be empty in the destination database. I don't want the empty rows to be 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. How can I modify
my SQL code to finish my goal?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you can do something like this:

```
nullif(<expression to convert col to date/time>, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```